# C++ 14 constexpr std::array

Tags: c++, gcc, c++14, constexpr

Изучаю constexpr.
Не могу понять, почему компилятор не рассматривает одно из выражений как константное, потому что оно подходит под требования.

Код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <array>

constexpr int f( int x ) 
{
    if ( x < 0 ) x = 0;
    return ++x;
}

int main()
{
    typedef double  T;
    typedef std::array<T, 3> C;

    constexpr C c = {1, 2, 3};
    constexpr C::const_reference ref = c.at( 0 ); //  error: is not a constexpr

    static_assert( ref == 1, "ref != 1" );

    constexpr int y = -3;
    //y = f( y );
    static_assert( f( y ) == 1, "f( y ) != 1" );

    return 0;
}
```

Можно скомпилировать по этой [ссылке](https://wandbox.org/permlink/PVNktFg5rqQrWzaZ)

В той реализации stl, с которой я работаю у array функция at объявлена как constexpr и у array нету конструкторов вообще, деструтор тоже не объявлен, а значит класс имеет деструктор по умолчанию, сам массив инициирован, поэтому я не знаю, почему это не работает.

Интересуют компиляторы gcc 5.4.0 и gcc 6.4.0.
clang тоже это не компилирует.

Answer (score 1):

Концепция "constexpr-ссылки" относится к свойствам самой ссылки, а не ссылаемого выражения. Constexpr-ссылка предполагает, что такая ссылка будет привязана к объекту, чье положение в памяти *известно на стадии компиляции*. Ситуация практически полностью аналогична таковой с constexpr-указателями.

Ваш *локальный* объект `c` этому требованию не удовлетворяет.

Объявите `c` как

```
static constexpr C c = {1, 2, 3};
```

и вы сможете привязывать к нему и его подобъектам `constexpr` ссылки.

---

(Иллюстрируя дополнительными примерами...) Вот такой код является корректным, несмотря на то, что ссылка привязывается к обычной неконстанстной переменной

```
int main()
{
  static int x = 42;
  constexpr const int &rx = x;
}
```

А вот такой код не является корректным, сколько бы `const` и `constexpr` мы бы на переменную ни навешивали

```
int main()
{
  constexpr int y = 42;
  constexpr const int &ry = y;
}
```

Comment: constexpr объект итак известен на стадии компиляции. https://wandbox.org/permlink/0bJWs6vfLT6ibp2Z

Comment: Это как это? *Значение* constexpr-объекта может быть известно на стадии компиляции.  *Положение в памяти* constexpr-объекта совсем не обязательно известно на стадии компиляции. (А именно: положение в памяти известно только для статических объектов). Constexpr-ссылки требуют именно известности положения в памяти. На значение им глубоко наплевать. Ваш пример по ссылке - совершенно мимо кассы, ибо в нем нет попыток объявления constexpr-ссылки.

Comment: Видимо, дело и впрямь в ссылках, но тот тест отрабатывал, я завтра если что отпишусь, и возможно будет ещё одна ошибка, ок? Просто, повторюсь, я пытался воспоизвести код по памяти, и возможно, что-то забыл.

Comment: В общем, в той реализации, с которой я работаю в at вызывается неконстантная функция. Потому и не работало. Стоило мне закомментировать вызов - всё скомпилировалось.

Comment: @OlegUP: В смысле "все скомпилировалось"? Что именно скомпилировалось?

Comment: В общем, в той реализации с которой я работаю из at вызывается неконстантная функция (std::abort()) что и является причиной ошибки.

Comment: Тот код, который я привёл.

Comment: Я закомментировал в реализации кусок кода, который вызывает abort() и тест прошёл.

Comment: Тот код, который вы привели в вопросе, никак не может компилироваться ни в какой стандартной реализации. Что это у вас за реализация такая?

Comment: Вот, тут уже не по памяти. https://wandbox.org/permlink/y3P1oCEQpbQhcH98

Comment: Но вообще, какой-то рандом, я писал функцию, которая вызывает не constexpr функцию, , чтобы всё это проверить, и у меня тоже всё компилировалось. Тут всё скомпилировалось только после правки непосредственно самой реализации array::at

Comment: @OlegUP: Ну к исходному вашему коду это все не имеет никакого отношения. Ключевой момент - constexpr ссылка.